# wordpress : unique page as about-us

Tags: wordpress, templates, unique

I’m doing my first wordpress template. I would like to get your opinion on the page templates that will only be used once (example: about-us). Instead, you recommend using

- page-{slug}.php
- as a template page (in the page-templates subfolder)
- a new post type

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be custom page template if you don't want any bindings with page slug/id. If the once used page is about us then create a **template-about.php** don't need to put it in subdirectory and **template-** prefix is pretty standard for the custom page template.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will take into account your answer to make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

For Page templates being used even once.

You can start with first method you listed i.e. page-{slug}.php
As benefit of it is that they are easy to keep track of in theme directory.

However with this approach you find face one issue later on, once someone like to change slug from e.g. about-us to 'about' , now that template will no more apply. So better to have template name also defined in the this page so this can be applied to any page easily from the dashboard incase of slug change or need to be applied to some other page in future.

```
<?php /* Template Name: About-us Page */ ?>
```

Source:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Also for other last approache you listed as CPT, I wanted to add that would not be good for single page template, as it is meant for collection of similar posts. Also it will generally have extra slug in the URLs now i.e. domain.com/cpt-slug/page-name

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will take into account your answer to make a decision.